# What is the nature of the Grinning Gargoyle at the end of Disney's "The Hunchback of Notre Dame"?

Tags: disney, hunchback-of-notre-dame

At the end of Disney's animated "The Hunchback of Notre Dame", the antagonist Frollo

> falls off the cathedral roof and grabs onto a gargoyle statue. The statue then begins glowing, grins evilly, and breaks off, thereby plummeting Frollo to his death.

**Was the significance of this scene, or the grinning gargoyle, ever explained in "behind-the-scenes" materials or interviews?**

I had three possible ideas:

- This gargoyle is alive like Quasimodo's three other stone-friends.
- It was purely a hallucination from Frollo's part (as he is turning mad at that moment)
- It was the Devil, or at least *a* devil, which incarnates temporarily in this gargoyle because he is already satisfied by the thought of soon having Frollo's soul.

These three hypotheses are only my thoughts about the possible answers, however. Here is a screenshot showing [**the scene in question**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3pMlKXAZWM):

[image]

Comment: [Google image search for "gargoyle" reveals many creepy smiles](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=isch&q=gargoyle&hl=en&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: You have 5 questions. Which one would you like answered?

Comment: @Jason Baker - As you can see at about 1:35 in [this clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3pMlKXAZWM), the gargoyle gives an *animated* grin in which its mouth opens wider and a glow starts to emanate from its mouth and eyes, it isn't just the ordinary static grin of a stone gargoyle.

Comment: It's a good question I haven't seen answered anywhere. I cleaned up the question and added a screenshot of the scene he's referring to.

Comment: Thank you for cleaning my question, but the glowing is not related with that: it is that (as we are in the middle of a battle) Quasimodo was basically throwing melting metal in the gargoyle, metal which was supposed to fall on the enemies downstairs. So the glowing is not related with the possible nature(s) of the gargoyle.

Comment: I always assumed Frollo was just going insane.  Having another "living" gargoyle like Quasimodo's friends is possible, I guess.  The devil idea seems unlikely, because it would raise even more questions-- are the other gargoyles also animated by devils? Or are they angels? Or something else?  (The movie implies that Quasimodo's friends are in his own imagination, but never explicitly addresses the subject.)

Comment: I always just assumed that all of the gargoyles were alive but generally kept that fact hidden from humans. Quasimodo's friends made an exception for him and this one made an exception in order to frighten Frollo into letting go. Whether that was because Frollo had shown his true colors or simply because all of the gargoyles are fond of Quasimodo, I couldn't say.

Answer (score 7):

I've heard two primary theories:

1. Frollo has completely lost his sanity.
2. The gargoyle is alive and passing judgement on Frollo.

Both of these theories tie into the rest of the movie neatly. This is especially because they relate to the parallel discussion of whether Hugo, Victor, and Laverne, Quasimodo's three gargoyle friends, are truly alive or merely Quasimodo's imagination. If Quasimodo invented the gargoyles out of his loneliness and isolation, then Frollo losing his mind to the point of having similar hallucinations makes his comeuppance that much more karmic.

By another interpretation, there are reasonable thematic reasons to believe the gargoyle Frollo saw was indeed alive. Hugo, Victor, and Laverne are treated ambiguously throughout the whole movie, so animate gargoyles are plausibly part of the story's setting. And symbolically, the Cathedral of Notre Dame is hinted to have a personality and force of will all to its own. At the beginning of the film, Frollo refuses to spare baby Quasimodo's life until he realizes the church's statues of the saints are staring at him. The animation and camerawork used makes the statues appear to be sentiently judging Frollo's actions. By this interpretation, the gargoyle that breaks on Frollo is another statue in the church judging his sins, deliberately condemning his soul. This is a strong symbolic and motivic bookend with the statues holding Frollo accountable to his murder at the film's opening.

---

I don't see much evidence to believe the gargoyle is an incarnation of a devil coming to take Frollo's soul. The imagery of Satan attacking humans is used in only one place in the film, during Frollo's "Hellfire" song, when the judge says, "God made the devil so much stronger than a man." Frollo says this as a way of trying to reject his responsibility for his sinful lust, so his reference to Satan is deliberately theologically flawed and dishonest. So this reference to Satan is less about establishing Satan as an important symbol or character in the story and more about revealing Frollo's heart.

Within this film, God is portrayed as the one who sends sinners to hell, not Satan. Consider again the scene with the statues silently judging Frollo. And throughout the movie, with the only unhinged exception above, Frollo consistently describes himself as carrying out God's judgement on sinners, sending them to hell where they righteously deserve to be.

All this considered, I find it doubtful that demons show up to claim Frollo's soul at the end of the film. They haven't showed up anywhere else in the film, and the only reference to them in the film comes from an unreliable character during one of his most thoroughly unhinged moments.

Comment: The way in which this answer infers authorial intent exclusively from the text—acknowledging and accounting for intentional ambiguity—makes for particularly compelling analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that there are two episodes in which Frollo has hallucinations and has red eyes. The first is during "Hellfire", and the second is before his death. In both cases he is surrounded by smoke that often makes your eyes turn red (wood smoke in particular releases a lot of carbon monoxide). So, I understand that it was symptoms of carbon monoxide poisoning.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  In order to be clear, your answer would be better if it started with the assertion that it was an hallucination, and then develop the argument why that is the case.